# React Navigation switch navigators without losing state

Tags: react-native, expo, react-navigation

I have a React Native Expo app and I am facing an issue related to react navigation. I am developing also web, so I want a responsive layout. Drawer navigator on large screens, bottom tabs navigator on small screen (like instagram).

The issue I am facing is that I lose my navigation state when resizing the window. If I am for example in the Profile tab, and I resize the window, then I will go to home in the Drawer navigator, and I want to stay in where I was (in the profile in this case).
Here's how I conditionally switch navigators:

```
      <MainStack.Screen
        name="main"
        component={
          screenSize.large ? SidebarMenuNavigator : BottomTabNavigator
        }
      />
```

My SidebarMenuNavigator looks like:

```
export default function SidebarMenuNavigator() {
  return (
    <SidebarMenu.Navigator
      initialRouteName="homeStack"
      screenOptions={{
        drawerType: "permanent"
      }}>
      <SidebarMenu.Screen
        name="homeStack"
        component={HomeStackNavigator}
        options={{
          title: "Home"
        }}
      />
      <SidebarMenu.Screen
        name="profileStack"
        component={ProfileStackNavigator}
        options={{
          title: "Profile"
        }}
      />
    </SidebarMenu.Navigator>
  );
}
```

And my BottomTabNavigator:

```
export default function BottomTabNavigator() {
  return (
    <BottomTab.Navigator
      initialRouteName="homeStack">
      <BottomTab.Screen
        name="homeStack"
        component={HomeStackNavigator}
        options={{
          title: "Home",
        }}
      />
      <BottomTab.Screen
        name="profileStack"
        component={ProfileStackNavigator}
        options={{
          title: "Profile"
        }}
      />
    </BottomTab.Navigator>
  );
}
```

How can I avoid to lose the state on navigator switch?